# List always shows only the first item c#

Tags: c#, list, addition

I'm building a medical app with wpf , and i've created a list for a patient's prescriptions , where i add them with a .add function. but it always only shows the last item added , rather than all of them. Any opinions? Thanks in advance!Below is my code :

```
private void AddMeds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MedNameAdd.Text != null && MedQuantAdd.Text != null && QuantType.Text != null)
    {
        List<string> medlist = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        medlist.Add(MedNameAdd.Text + "   " + MedQuantAdd.Text + "     " + QuantType.Text);
        MedList.ItemsSource = medlist;
        Address.Text = medlist[i];
        i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you create new list each time. And adding only 1 element. So the result is a list with one element..

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new `List` everytime, Move the declaration to outside function.

```
List<string> medlist = new List<string>();

private void AddMeds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MedNameAdd.Text != null && MedQuantAdd.Text != null && QuantType.Text != null)
    {   
        medlist.Add(MedNameAdd.Text + "   " + MedQuantAdd.Text + "     " + QuantType.Text);
        MedList.ItemsSource = medlist;
        Address.Text = medlist.LastOrDefault(); // shows last added item.    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in your code you always created new *empty* list and add it as `ItemSource`. Instead, re-use the existing one

```
   if (MedNameAdd.Text != null && MedQuantAdd.Text != null && QuantType.Text != null)
   {
       var medlist = MedList.ItemsSource as List<string>;
       int i = 0;
       medlist.Add(MedNameAdd.Text + "   " + MedQuantAdd.Text + "     " + QuantType.Text);
       Address.Text = medlist[i];
       i++; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The list `medList` is local in the method `AddMeds_Click`, which means that it is newly created in every call.

Comment: i tried that , but it doesn't recognize it later because it's outside the click function

Answer (score 1):

Because every time a new one is added, you receate the data source from scratch, only adding the newly added item, and wiping all previously added items.

Move the declaration of the `List<string>` outside of the click event handler:

```
List<string> medlist = new List<string>();
private void AddMeds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MedNameAdd.Text != null && MedQuantAdd.Text != null && QuantType.Text != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            medlist.Add(MedNameAdd.Text + "   " + MedQuantAdd.Text + "     " + QuantType.Text);
            MedList.ItemsSource = medlist;
            Address.Text = medlist[i];
            i++; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are creating new instance of List Class every time in event handler and adding only one item:

```
   medlist.Add(MedNameAdd.Text + "   " + MedQuantAdd.Text + "     " + QuantType.Text);
```

so instantiate your list as a class member and use that list object in event handler to hold the values in it like this way:

```
List<string> medlist = new List<string>();

private void AddMeds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MedNameAdd.Text != null && MedQuantAdd.Text != null && QuantType.Text != null)
    {
        int i = 0;
        medlist.Add(MedNameAdd.Text + "   " + MedQuantAdd.Text + "     " + QuantType.Text);
        MedList.ItemsSource = medlist;
        Address.Text = medlist[i];
        i++; 
    }
}
```